# Swagger-UI generated python server not starting due to 'no module named' error

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, swagger, pypi, connexion

I'm working with an OpenAPI 3.0.1 yaml and it's unable to get the API webserver started due to the below error. I tried almost everything that is under my knowledge but I'm very new at OpenAPI and the documentation was followed as it is. Any thoughts on what could be wrong here?

This is the error on loading up the server:

```
Failed to add operation for GET /v2/catalog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\connexion\apis\abstract.py", line 209, in add_paths
    self.add_operation(path, method)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\connexion\apis\abstract.py", line 162, in add_operation
    operation = make_operation(
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\connexion\operations\__init__.py", line 8, in make_operation
    return spec.operation_cls.from_spec(spec, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\connexion\operations\openapi.py", line 128, in from_spec
    return cls(
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\connexion\operations\openapi.py", line 75, in __init__
    super(OpenAPIOperation, self).__init__(
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\connexion\operations\abstract.py", line 96, in __init__
    self._resolution = resolver.resolve(self)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\connexion\resolver.py", line 40, in resolve
    return Resolution(self.resolve_function_from_operation_id(operation_id), operation_id)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\connexion\resolver.py", line 64, in resolve_function_from_operation_id
    raise ResolverError(msg, sys.exc_info())
connexion.exceptions.ResolverError: <ResolverError: Cannot resolve operationId "catalog.get"! Import error was "No module named 'catalog'">

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\API\swagger_server\__main__.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\API\swagger_server\__main__.py", line 18, in main
    app.add_api('D:\API\swagger_server\swagger\swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': 'GPI API Broker'}, pythonic_params=True)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\connexion\apps\flask_app.py", line 57, in add_api
    api = super(FlaskApp, self).add_api(specification, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\connexion\apps\abstract.py", line 141, in add_api
    api = self.api_cls(specification,
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\connexion\apis\abstract.py", line 111, in __init__
    self.add_paths()
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\connexion\apis\abstract.py", line 216, in add_paths
    self._handle_add_operation_error(path, method, err.exc_info)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\connexion\apis\abstract.py", line 231, in _handle_add_operation_error
    raise value.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\connexion\resolver.py", line 61, in resolve_function_from_operation_id
    return self.function_resolver(operation_id)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\connexion\utils.py", line 110, in get_function_from_name
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'catalog'
```

The startup command is basically: **python -m swagger_server**

Finally, this is part of my YAML where the operationId is mentioned:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Open Service Broker API
  description: The Open Service Broker API defines an HTTP(S) interface between Platforms
    and Service Brokers.
  contact:
    name: Open Service Broker API
    url: https://www.openservicebrokerapi.org/
    email: open-service-broker-api@googlegroups.com
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
  version: master - might contain changes that are not yet released
externalDocs:
  description: The offical Open Service Broker API specification
  url: https://github.com/openservicebrokerapi/servicebroker/
servers:
- url: http://localhost:80/
- url: https://localhost:80/
security:
- basicAuth: []
paths:
  /v2/catalog:
    get:
      tags:
      - Catalog
      summary: get the catalog of services that the service broker offers
      operationId: 'catalog.get'
      parameters:
      - name: X-Broker-API-Version
        in: header
...
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: `operationId: 'catalog.get'` in Python terms means `from catalog import get`. Do you have a module or a package `catalog` from which you can import name `get`?

Comment: Yes. In my D:\API\swagger_server\models I have the modules and one of them is catalog.py:

# coding: utf-8

from __future__ import absolute_import
from datetime import date, datetime  # noqa: F401

from typing import List, Dict  # noqa: F401

from swagger_server.models.base_model_ import Model
from swagger_server.models.service import Service  # noqa: F401,E501
from swagger_server import util


class Catalog(Model):
    """NOTE: This class is auto generated by the swagger code generator program.
...

Comment: The operationId must be relative to where you run your app. For example, if your app is run in the directory swagger_server, you need to specify in your yml 'models.catalog.get'.

Comment: Thanks, @above_c_level. This fix that issue.
I'm having another one now: "AttributeError: module 'models.catalog' has no attribute 'get'", but I believe that this is something wrong with the code generated by the swagger, as if the YAML specifies it, the module should have the get attribute, right?

Comment: Maybe 'get' is just a default value. I think Connexion defines such default values. However, you can just open your catalog.py and look if there is a function get(). If not, you have to write one. :)

Comment: Well, it doesn't. I'm still not quite sure if it should be working as it is, even though I'm using the skeleton provided by openApi and the server provided by swagger, it is nothing as an easy service start with dummy face to be customized, it's a challenge to be fixing every piece of the code trying to make that to even start the web server. Very frustrating indeed.

Comment: Hey @above_c_level, can you put your first response as an answer? I'm gonna mark this as answered and I want to give you credits for that.
Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operationId must be relative to where your app is running.

```
swagger_server
|-- app.py
|-- __init__.py
|-- OpenAPI
|   |-- openapi.yml
|-- models
|   |-- catalog.py
```

Given the above folder structure, you start the app in the directory swagger_server. Consequently, the path of `app.py` is in your `sys.path`. Relative to this path you need to specify the `operationId` in your `openapi.yml`:

```
paths:
  /v2/catalog:
    get:
      tags:
      - Catalog
      summary: get the catalog of services that the service broker offers
      operationId: 'models.catalog.get'
```

The file catalog.py must contain a function `def get(name)`. Here you can define your service/handler for the endpoint. It must include the parameter `name` because you have specified the parameter in your YAML file.